# WOULD LIKE TO HAVE + PP for possible accomplishments vs FUTURE PERFECT

Tags: perfect-constructions, future, would

How does "would like to have + past participle" compare with future perfect. Is future perfect something planned out and expected while "would like to have + pp" describes more of a general desire?

I'll have earned my degree by next year.

I would like to have earned my degree by next year.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The first sentence expresses a certainty, the second expresses cautious optimism. (A first degree course normally lasts several years, so the speaker must have some reason to fear that they may not be able to complete their final year!)

Answer (score 1):

In the most general terms:

> I will

expresses a plan, intention, or resolution, whereas

> I would like to

expresses a desire, wish, or hope.